# Lie-Trotter Theorem proof

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Does anyone know how to prove Lie-Trotter theorem: $e^{-iA}e^{-iB}=e^{-i(A+B)}+\mathcal{O}(\delta^{2})$ whereby, $||A||, ||B||<\delta$ and $\mathcal{O}(\delta^{2})$ is shorthand for some arbitrary operator, $E$, where $||E||<\delta^{2}$.

Comment: Use a norm operator on the $d \times d$ complex matrices and the fact that $$||e^M-I-M|| = \Big|\Big|\sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{M^k}{k!} \Big|\Big| \le \sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{||M||^k}{k!} =  e^{||M||}-1-||M|| = O(||M||^2).$$